# How to create lazy load effect with jquery with the same class elements showing them on scoll after each other and with loading when it is hidden

Tags: jquery, scroll, lazy-loading

I have elements with the same class and I need to show them on scroll like lazy load effect.I tried this code

```
jQuery(window).scroll( function(){
    jQuery('.scrollable_section').each( function(i){
        var bottom_of_object = jQuery(this).position().top + jQuery(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height();
        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){
            jQuery(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},500, function(){
                jQuery(this).addClass('activeSection');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

It is working fine on desktop but on tablet it showed elements not in the proper scroll position, I need to scroll and scroll and then it shows.